# Knit one markdown file to two output files

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a way to knit a single .md file to a .html or .docx in the working directory in R and simultaneously post a copy of the .html to another folder, possibly on another drive?

Alternatively, can the 'publish' button in RStudio be used to send a .md file to a location other than RPubs?

Comment: This is somewhat of a guess, but maybe you could use an output hook.  http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/#output_hooks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's possible to render multiple outputs, but not with the "knit" Button in RStudio. Write your desired output in the YAML header and then use `output_format = "all"` as argument in

`rmarkdown::render(<your-rmd-file.rmd>, output_format ="all")`

So the YAML header looks like:

```
title: "multiple outputs"
output:
     word_document: default
     html_document: default
```

Or any option you want to set for the different output formats.

I don't know if it is possible to set different output directories, but I don't think so.

Comment: A way to render it in two directories would be: `render(rmd.rmd, output_format="word_document", output_dir="./doc") ; render(rmd.rmd, output_format="html_document", output_dir="./html") ;`

Comment: That's clear ... with 2 function calls you can knit the file in two folders.

Comment: Nice one guys. Cheers!

Comment: @J_F Is it possible to divide multiple sections of the same RMD doc into multiple `word_document` files?

Comment: Unfortunately this is quite impractical because render() only works on a per-file basis. tools::buildVignettes technically scouts the vignettes directory, then binds each file to its specific engine. The rest of the machinery basically invokes each engine and builds each vignette with its appropriate engine. You would have to reimplement this logic in whatever driver code (e.g. bash script) to bind and execute each file if you have multiple vignettes with different engines.

Answer (score 26):

Actually, the knit button can indeed -

- Render multiple outputs.
- Use a custom output directory.

Example with output directory called `output`:

```
title: "multiple outputs"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_dir = "output", output_format = "all") })
```

Comment: Probably one of the most useful answers regarding the `rmarkdown`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Apparently, this solution is now obsolete. I could not make it work today. It seems to simply ignore the knit: option