# Knit one markdown file to two output files using the knit button

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am interested in rendering multiple outputs using the knit button.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280491/13257018) but I do not understand how to edit the `knit:` call to do just that.

Thank you for any pointer,
Ivan

Comment: If you don't understand an answer, post a comment asking for clarification, don't ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Since I'm a new user I am not allowed to comment. And I tried "adding another answer", but my post was just deleted.

Comment: sorry about that.  Sounds like SO has some bad rules.

Comment: You probably could describe the code you have as well as the desired result and your result (e.g. potential error codes etc)

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it, this is what I need:

```
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, 
                    encoding = encoding, 
                    output_format = "all", 
                    knit_root_dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file()) 
  })
```

There might be a better way to find the project directory though, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280491/13257018) as YAML header

```
---
title: "multiple outputs"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_format = "all") })
---

TEST
```

Comment: OK, so the problem is somewhere else, and probably with the working directory during the rendering. 
Apparently, when I use this command, the file is not knitted anymore in the project directory. And since I access files in different folders relative to the project directory, this is needed.
What can I do then?

Comment: I edited my answer and removed the output folder from the command.

Comment: I could use the here() package, but it would be nice to still be able to knit in the project directory with this command.

Comment: Is it possible to divide multiple sections of the same RMD doc into multiple `word_document` files?